# How to change colors in different parts of Windows Explorer in W10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, colors

A search brought me here (but was not a place to ask further and only answer hence here I am)  [How to change highlighting color on folder selection windows 10 in file explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1287491/how-to-change-highlighting-color-on-folder-selection-windows-10-in-file-explorer)

Regarding WinToolsInfo and other comments made in the above link:
My concern is how do I change the color of the space around everything in Explorer (See a,b,c,d,e,f in attached image)--mainly what is white (and if you turn it to dark mode it becomes black). I want that to be light grey (I find dark mode the exact problem as the current 'white' mode, except in reverse. I also would like to see that invisible line that separates the panes, especially the right pane (that views the content of the file--"G" in attached image)
Thank you
[image: Explorer details]

Comment: Windows Explorer is built into Windows 10 and even more so in Windows 11. You might wish to consider a 3rd party file explorer with more flexibility.  xPlorer2 has some color coding and there are lots of other 3rd party file tools.